# MVC using FileExtensionsAttribute in custom editor template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to use my custom resource uploader template to upload a resource for my model but I can't find a way to get FileExtensions data annotation attribute metadata:

**ViewModel**:

```
public class ItemViewModel{
    [Required]
    public Name {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Resource"), FileExtensions(Extensions = ".res")]
    public UploadedResourceID{get;set;}
}
```

**View**:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@* My Resource Uploader *@
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UploadedResourceID, "ResourceUploader")
```

ResourceUploader **EditorTemplate**:

```
@model Guid?
@Html.LabelFor(model => model)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model)
<input 
       id="My_Custom_Ajax_Uploader_That_Populates_The_Hidden_Field"
       accept="@Html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.???????"
/>
... some ajax logic to upload the resource ...
```

I looked through `ModelMetadata`'s fields in my template, but couldn't find a way to get `FileExtensions` attribute.

Comment: This attribute just validates that the extension is what you say it should be. I don't think it provides much else.

Comment: @MikeCheel, well I see it as a data attribute on HTML rendered hidden input (so it's passed into the template somehow), so I'm just wondering if I can access it in my EditorTemplate's view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a somehow ugly way to achieve this:

```
var metaData = Html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata;
var prop = metaData.ContainerType.GetProperty(metaData.PropertyName);
var fileExtAttrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (FileExtensionsAttribute), false);
```